# Looking for a fix in my RegEx to parse the correct value

Tags: regex, ant

I have 3 lines:

`<entry key="SvsAdapter" value-ref="svsAdapter"/>
<entry key="AdyenAdapter" value-ref="adyenAdapter" />
<entry key="PaymentExpressAdapter" value-ref="paymentExpressAdapter"/>`

I need to parse the key from them except SvsAdapter.
In Ant script I have:

`<containsregex pattern="&lt;entry.*key=&quot;(.*?[^Svs]Adapter).*" replace="\1" flags="i" />`

But as you see the [^Svs] is not correct one. 
Could someone help me to create the right one?

Comment: Are you... editing an Ant script with another Ant script?

Comment: Yeap. I have my first ant xml running and preparing the right config in the next ant xml, which will be run after.

Comment: Why not just set the key to a property? I can guarantee you there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Unfortunate we have a configuration file. And we need to take a key from this config file and to compare with the key from another. If they are the same and only then to do some replaces / leave as it is. But config file has it`s own structure =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way for rejecting `SvsAdapter` you need to write your negative look ahead like this,

```
<entry key="(?!SvsAdapter\b)([a-zA-Z]+)\b.*
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6tPrEb/2)**

Hence, the string you need to write becomes,

```
pattern="&lt;entry key=&quot;(?!SvsAdapter\b)([a-zA-Z]+)\b.*"
```

Comment: I need to get not the whole line, but AdyenAdapter and PaymentExpressAdapter

Comment: @SergheiSanduleac: Updated my answer. Can you check now?

Comment: Yeah! Thanks a lot, now it works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help :) And do consider accepting my answer which will give you +2 rep and may help other users looking for a solution similar to yours.

Comment: Yeah thanks, it was my first question and I did not know how to do it. But now seems I accepted it! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I saw this was your first day of joining SO, which is why I thought I should tell you about it. Also, your posted question is well phrased as you have posted relevant sample data and shown your efforts which makes it overall good and increases the chances and makes it easy for others to help you. Good job on your first day asking a question. You may further browse the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) which will help you become a good SO user :)